# How to create Linkedhashset using Hashset?

Tags: linkedhashset

I was asked this question during my interview "How to create Linkedhashset using Hashset ?" anyone knows the answer ?

Comment: Java? And what do you mean by "using Hashset"?

Comment: yes for Java, basically an HashSet which behaves like LinkedHashSet, the order of insertion is preserved. Say, I only have HashSet and want to make it behave like LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class has a `public LinkedHashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor, so you could do

```
HashSet<Foo> hs = new HashSet<Foo>();
// add items...
LinkedHashSet<Foo> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>(hs);
```

to get a LinkedHashSet instance with the same content as `hs`. Note that there is no guarantee that the items from `hs` are inserted into `lhs` in the same order they were inserted into `hs`, since that information was never saved by `hs`.

There is no way to make "an HashSet which behaves like LinkedHashSet", that is, an instance of runtime class `HashSet` that behaves like a `LinkedHashSet` instance. However, you could do

```
HashSet<Foo> hs = new LinkedHashSet<Foo>();
```

which would give you an instance that would be seen by the outside world as a plain `HashSet` but use the `LinkedHashSet` implementation internally. I fail to see why you would ever want to do that, though - you would only gain a bunch of overhead and no added functionality, since the declared type is `HashSet`. The reason you'd want to use a LinkedHashSet in the first place is to be guaranteed the predictable iteration order, but you still wouldn't be able to assume that for `hs` - you could assign `hs = new HashSet<Foo>()` at any time, for instance.

Comment: It's considered good manners to accept an answer that helped you. :)